# Handler behavior in Android

Tags: android, handler

I am creating an handler as shown below,

```
postTimer = new Handler();
postHandler = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
 Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
 msg.arg1 = SYNC_USAGE_STAT;
 mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);              
}
};
postTimer.postDelayed(postHandler, 15000);
```

Does this give a single timeout or is it like heartbeat.

Comment: If you want to implement like Heartbeat then **TimerTask** is there in Android.

Answer (score 1):

That's a one time event. You can do the same thing in your runnable (`postTimer.postDelayed(postHandler, 15000);` I mean), so it will behave like heartbeat, but you would need some kind of flag to stop it somewhere in the future.